# Cannot Boot into the GUI Mode after Installing "ATI binary X.Org driver" from Ubuntu Software Center

Tags: ati, hard-drive, hardware, gui

The computer cannot boot into the GUI Mode after installing "ATI binary X.Org driver" from Ubuntu software center.
Now I boot into recovery mode -> root -> `mount -o remount,rw /`.

What can I do to fix the problem?
How to delete "ATI binary X.Org driver"?

Thank you for your attention

```
------------------------------------------------------------
Desktop Information
------------------------------------------------------------
OS           : Ubuntu 14.04 LTS (64 bits)
Display Card : MSI R4770 Cyclone (ATI Radeon HD 4770)*
CPU          : AMD Athlon II X4 620
------------------------------------------------------------
* "No additional drivers available" in "Additional Driver" page
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can "reconfigure" xorg or remove the driver and reinstall and check if it helps. If that doesn't help, I'd recommend you to re-install the default ones.

1st Try and reconfigure the Xserver conf, (assuming you're in the terminal, type the following):

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure xserver-xorg
```

And after that, try and reboot your system.
If that dint help either, you can try and remove the ATI drivers and use the default ones.

For which,type the following:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge fglrx fglrx_* fglrx-amdcccle* fglrx-dev*
```

After which you need to Remove your xorg.conf

```
sudo rm /etc/X11/xorg.conf
```

If the ATI drivers are still not working, you can try and revert to "default" ones, so Reinstall xorg

For 32bits systems

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall xserver-xorg-core libgl1-mesa-glx libgl1-mesa-dri
```

For 64bits systems

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall libgl1-mesa-glx:i386 libgl1-mesa-glx:amd64 libgl1-mesa-    dri:i386 libgl1-mesa-dri:amd64 xserver-xorg-core
```

Configure Xorg, 
Now reboot the Machine,

```
sudo reboot
```

After the reboot all the fglrx packages will be gone, you will be using default drivers and hopefully you should be in the "Normal" mode, do let me know if you need anything.

Comment: "sudo rm /etc/X11/xorg.conf" : rm: cannot remove 'sudo rm /etc/X11/xorg.conf': No such file or directory.

Now what can I do?

Comment: "sudo apt-get install --reinstall libgl1-mesa-glx:i386 libgl1-mesa-glx:amd64 libgl1-mesa-    dri:i386 libgl1-mesa-dri:amd64 xserver-xorg-core":
    Reading package lists... Done 
    Building dependency tree 
    Reading state information... Done 
    E: Unable to locate package libgl1-mesa 
    E: Unable to locate package dri

Answer (score 1):

If you have an ATI graphics card, the "ATI binary X.Org driver" is what you would get my default after doing updates. The updater detects what you have and adds the right wrapper.

You can `sudo apt-get remove xserver-xorg-video-ati` and `sudo startx`